# RMI: ClassNotFoundException thrown while binding two remote objects to same registry

Tags: java, security, tomcat, classloader, rmi

I have a two Remote Objects that I'm trying to bind to the same RMI Registry. Here's my project structure:

My first class(RemoteServer1.java)

```
package com.abc.rmi;

import java.rmi.AccessException;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class RemoteServer1 implements IServer1Interface{

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RemoteServer1.class);

public void init(){
    Registry localRegistry = null;
    IServer1Interface server1 = null;
    try
    {
      int port = 1099;
      logger.info("Service Property rmiRegistryPort: " + port);
      server1 = (IServer1Interface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
      logger.info("Locating registry");
      localRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
      try
      {
        localRegistry.list();
      }
      catch (RemoteException localRemoteException2)
      {
        logger.info("Creating registry");
        try
        {
          localRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        }
        catch (RemoteException localRemoteException4)
        {
          logger.error("Server1 RemoteException. " + localRemoteException4);
          throw new RuntimeException("Server1 - Registry creation failed. ", localRemoteException4);
        }
      }
      logger.info("Binding");
      localRegistry.bind("Server1", server1);
    }
    catch (AlreadyBoundException localAlreadyBoundException)
    {
      logger.warn("Server1 - Object already bound." + localAlreadyBoundException);
      try
      {
        logger.info("Re-Binding");
        localRegistry.rebind("Server1", server1);
      }
      catch (AccessException localAccessException)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server1 - AccessException while re-binding. ", localAccessException);
      }
      catch (RemoteException localRemoteException3)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server1 - RemoteException while re-binding. ", localRemoteException3);
      }
    }
    catch (RemoteException localRemoteException1)
    {
      logger.error("Server1 RemoteException. " + localRemoteException1);
      throw new RuntimeException("Server1 - RemoteException. ", localRemoteException1);
    }
    logger.info("Remote Server1 ready");
}

}
```

Here's my second class(RemoteServer2.java)

```
package com.abc.rmi2;

import java.rmi.AccessException;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class RemoteServer2 implements IServer2Interface{

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RemoteServer2.class);

public void init(){
    Registry localRegistry = null;
    IServer2Interface server2 = null;
    try
    {
      int port = 1099;
      logger.info("Service Property rmiRegistryPort: " + port);
      server2 = (IServer2Interface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
      logger.info("Locating registry");
      localRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
      try
      {
        localRegistry.list();
      }
      catch (RemoteException localRemoteException2)
      {
        logger.info("Creating registry");
        try
        {
          localRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        }
        catch (RemoteException localRemoteException4)
        {
          logger.error("Server2 RemoteException. " + localRemoteException4);
          throw new RuntimeException("Server2 - Registry creation failed. ", localRemoteException4);
        }
      }
      logger.info("Binding");
      localRegistry.bind("Server2", server2);
    }
    catch (AlreadyBoundException localAlreadyBoundException)
    {
      logger.warn("Server2 - Object already bound." + localAlreadyBoundException);
      try
      {
        logger.info("Re-Binding");
        localRegistry.rebind("Server2", server2);
      }
      catch (AccessException localAccessException)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server2 - AccessException while re-binding. ", localAccessException);
      }
      catch (RemoteException localRemoteException3)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server2 - RemoteException while re-binding. ", localRemoteException3);
      }
    }
    catch (RemoteException localRemoteException1)
    {
      logger.error("Server2 RemoteException. " + localRemoteException1);
      throw new RuntimeException("Server2 - RemoteException. ", localRemoteException1);
    }
    logger.info("Remote Server2 ready");
}

}
```

IServer1Interface and IServer2Interface implement java.rmi.remote. The class RemoteServer1.java is able to register with the RMI registry, but I get the following exception when the line "localRegistry.rebind("Server2", server2)" is called in the second class(RemoteServer2.java):

```
03-06-2014 18:03:43 ERROR RemoteServer2: - Server2 RemoteException. java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.rmi2.IServer2Interface (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I'm running this inside a Tomcat server using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("file:///C:/temp/rmi/rmi1.jar");
    URL[] urls = {url};
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.abc.rmi.RemoteServer1", true, child);
    Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("init");
    Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
    Object result = method.invoke(instance);

    URL url2 = new URL("file:///C:/temp/rmi/rmi2.jar");
    URL[] urls2 = {url2};
    URLClassLoader child2 = new URLClassLoader(urls2, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class classToLoad2 = Class.forName("com.abc.rmi2.RemoteServer2", true, child2);
    Method method2 = classToLoad2.getDeclaredMethod("init");
    Object instance2 = classToLoad2.newInstance();
    Object result2 = method2.invoke(instance2);
```

I haven't defined any security manager while starting up Tomcat and I haven't made any changes to the Tomcat Security policy. What I don't understand is how it is able to bind the first remote class fine, but not the second one. I've read in many places that a Security Manager must be defined for RMI to work, but it is able to load the first class without any issues. Why does this problem occur only when I try to bind the second class. I also read about the property 'java.rmi.server.codebase', but I'm not sure how the first one got loaded even though I didn't specify this property. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The *Registry* doesn't have the second class available via its CLASSPATH or via the codebase feature. So there is something wrong with one of those.

Comment: The first class also has not been specified in either CLASSPATH or codebase. But the registry is able to find it. That's what is confusing me!

Comment: The Registry is started after you've loaded the first class and before you've loaded the second class.